# angular and double slash signature in styles

Tags: angular, sass

I created an angular project in version 13. I tried to add some styles and I wanted to set some comments in my code. I added a double slash before comment text, and then I got the following error:

```
postcss-import: D:\workspace\kakebo\src\app\styles\variables\colors.scss Unknown word

> 1 | // Colors palette
    |    ^
  2 | $white: #ffffff;
```

It forces me to use `/* */` instead of a double slash, but I would like to stay with `//` signature. How can I achieve that in angular project?

Comment: Just // is not a valid comment for css and post-css (nothing to do with Angular btw) borks on it (and rightfully so).

Answer (score 0):

A CSS comment is placed inside the  element, and starts with /* and ends with */